# Datatable con laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, web, datatables

Estoy utilizando datatables para mostrar la información de mis clientes y algunos otros campos de utilidad, la datatable funciona perfectamente, pero ahora  necesito crear reportes segun la consulta hecha con el buscador de la datatable.

a través del metodo getElementsByTagName('tr').. obtengo la información de cada valor de la columna de la consulta, pero este metodo me la retorna como una collection de html... necesito poder enviar esa collection al controlador y no funciona, no reconoce la información... hay alguna forma de poder hacer esto lo que he intentado hasta ahora no me a funcionado ... estoy usando laravel. adjunto el codigo gracias de antemano...

```
 $("#omg").click(function() {
    var info = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    var route= 'pdf/'+info+'/';
    alert(info[0].innerHTML );
    $.ajax({
            url: route,
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(result)
            {
               console.log('done');
            },
            fail: function(){
               console.log('fracaso');
            }
        });    
});

$('#logs').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    //"serverSide": true,
    "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
    "language": {
                "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Spanish.json"
                  },
});
```

el #omg es un id de un botón con el cual se generan los reportes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tengo entendido que al ejecutar getElementsByTagName solo te recolectaria la información de los td visibles y omitiria los ocultos que puedan estar por la paginación de dataTable, en caso de ser muchos registros, creo que una de tus opciones podria ser usar el metodo GetData el cual te devolveria toda la información de la tabla en un arreglo.

```
$("#table").dataTable().fnGetData()
```

Te adjunto el link de metodos del api dataTable porfavor nota la "d" minuscula, ya que existen otros metodos con "D" mayuscula favor de no confundir.
http://legacy.datatables.net/ref

Comment: Gracias, me fue muy útil la documentación que me compartiste, hay métodos muy interesantes